# width:100% vs. width:inherit

Tags: html, css

My understanding is that `width: 100%` lets the element's width be the same as its parent's, whereas `width: inherit` does that only when the parent's width is explicitly specified. Is this understanding correct?

If so, it looks to me that when `width: inherit` works, then `width: 100%` would always work, so you could always use the latter. Then, what is the purpose of writing `width: inherit`? When does it become useful?

If my understanding is wrong, what is the difference between the two?

Similarly with `height`.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

See jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bt5nj/2/ and http://jsfiddle.net/bt5nj/3/

`width:inherit` inherits width that defined by **parent**.

**HTML:**

```html
  <div id="parent">
      <div id="child"></div>
  </div>​
```

**CSS:**

```css
  #parent {
      width:50%;
      height:30px;
  }

  #child {
      width:inherit;
      height:100%;
      background-color:red;
  }
```

This makes `child` width 25%, but if I redefine it with `width:100%` it will define width of `child` 50%.

​

Comment: I see. So inherit copies the literal expression rather than the value.

Comment: @Chuck Norris - why 25%? ..do child's inherently get half of the total amount?

Comment: @LeonelGurdian - Because parent's width is 50% and we are inheriting same 50% for the width of the child. 50% of the 50% percent is the 25% of total.

Comment: @sawa does it? According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit it copies the computed value rather than the literal value in the css.